# no matching fuction for call to LiquidCrystal

Tags: arduino

Me sale un error no matching fuction for call to LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const char [9]
El error es en la parte

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd (I2C_ADDR, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3,"POSITIVE") ;

Answer (score 0):

Estas inicializando el LCD como si fuera el modelo antiguo, pero usando la librería para el modelo I2C.

Si estas usando un display con interfaz I2C, la declaración correcta es:

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t lcd_Addr,uint8_t lcd_cols,uint8_t lcd_rows);
```

con I2C no necesitas especificar pines, pues la comunicación se realiza mediante los pines predeterminados (A4, A5 por default).

Los parámetros son:

- lcd_Addr es la dirección del display en el bus I2C.
- lcd_cols es el número de columnas.
- lcd_rows es el número de filas.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print("Ywrobot Arduino!");
   lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("Arduino LCM IIC 2004");
   lcd.setCursor(2,3);
  lcd.print("Power By Ec-yuan!");
}


void loop()
{
}
```